# Understanding Auth::check method - how it works under the hood

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created the following method in my admin controller:

```
public function index() {
    // $recentBlogPost = DB::table('Admin')->get();
    // Auth::logout();

    if (!(Auth::check())) {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }       

    $tags = DB::table('Tags')->get();
    /* convert Object to array */
    $tagsArray = array();
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tagsArray[$tag->tag] = $tag->tag; 
    }
    $tagsArray = json_decode(json_encode($tagsArray) , TRUE);
    return view('admin.index')->with('tags' , $tagsArray);
}
```

Now i see the following line of code

```
(Auth::check())
```

I got this code from the laravel docs here ->https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

I would reallly like to know that that class or method is really doing under the hood , which file do i pull up for me to have a sneak peak to the code under the hood.

Comment: Side note: you don't really need the surrounding parenthesis. Documentation sample does not use them.

Answer (score 1):

## Auth::check()

```
// Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers
/**
 * Determine if the current user is authenticated.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

If you want to know `$this->user()`:

```
// Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard
/**
 * Get the currently authenticated user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function user()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) {
        return;
    }

    // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
    // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
    // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
    if (! is_null($this->user)) {
        return $this->user;
    }

    $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

    // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
    // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
    // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
    $user = null;

    if (! is_null($id)) {
        if ($user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id)) {
            $this->fireAuthenticatedEvent($user);
        }
    }

    // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
    // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
    // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
    $recaller = $this->getRecaller();

    if (is_null($user) && ! is_null($recaller)) {
        $user = $this->getUserByRecaller($recaller);

        if ($user) {
            $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

            $this->fireLoginEvent($user, true);
        }
    }

    return $this->user = $user;
}
```

### How it happen?

1. You're using facade/helper - `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`, but there are no check method.
2. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` extends `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`
3. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` has a magic `__callStatic()` method
4. `__callStatic` execs `check` method on 'auth' instance
5. 'auth' instance/singleton is registered in `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::registerAuthenticator()`
6. Ok, it means 'auth' instance is a 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager'
7. There is no 'check' method, but 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager' has a magic `__call` method
8. `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::__call()` execs 'check' method on 'guard' instance
9. `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::guard()` inits a `guard` according to your `configs/auth.php`
10. By default `guard` - `session` (`Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`)
11. `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` does not have `check` method, but it uses `Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers` trait
12. `Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers` has `check` method

**In other word Auth facade:**

1. Execs facade methods
2. If facade method not found, execs `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` methods
3. If AuthManager method not found, execs guard(and guard trait) methods

Answer (score 0):

To understand how it works it's better to look at the [`check()`](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/5.3/GuardHelpers.php#L47) method source code:

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

So it's just checking if user instance exists or not and returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Here is the link to the API docs https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Guard.html

Comment: That's why I prefer to code with an IDE where I can just Ctrl+Click on a function and see its implementation.